# BeanIO how to skip/filter @Group in fixedLength

Tags: bean-io, fixed-length-file

I'm trying to read a fixedlength file.
I want to extract list of Document, but ***filtered*** only with RecordHeader (RH) with field value "BB".
So skip Document with recordHeader equals:

```
RH20210607AA
```

This is an example of my class Document

```
@Group
public class Document{

    @Record(order = 1, minOccurs=1, maxOccurs=1)
    private RH recordHeader;
    @Record(order = 2, minOccurs=1, maxOccurs = -1, type=RD.class, collection = List.class)
    private List<RD> recordDetails;
}
```

This is an example of my class RH

```
@Record
public class RH{

    @Field(ordinal = 0, required = true, length = 2, align = Align.LEFT, rid = true, literal = "RH")
    private String recordType;

    @Field(ordinal = 1, required = true, length=8, format = "yyyyMMdd")
    private LocalDate documentDate;

    @Field(ordinal = 2, required = true, length = 2, padding = ' ', align = Align.LEFT)
    private String documentCode;
}
```

This is an example of fixedLength file:

```
fake
Unknown record
Unknown record
RH20210607AA    
RDitem1
RDitem2
Unknown record
RH20210607BB    
RDitem2
RDitem3
Unknown record
Unknown record
Unknown record
RH20210607BB    
RDitem1
RDitem4
RDitem5
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use more than one field on your `RH` class to identify the records you want. You can do this:

```
@Record
public class RH {

  @Field(ordinal = 0, required = true, length = 2, align = Align.LEFT, rid = true, literal = "RH")
  private String recordType;

  @Field(ordinal = 1, required = true, length = 8, format = "yyyyMMdd")
  private Date documentDate;

  @Field(ordinal = 2, required = true, length = 2, padding = ' ', align = Align.LEFT, rid = true, literal = "BB")
  private String documentCode;

}
```

Note the extra attributes on the `@Field` annotation for the `documentCode` field --> `rid = true, literal = "BB"`

You can use a regular expression in place of the `literal = "BB"` if you need to include more `RH` records or use it as an exclusion filter.

You are probably already doing it, you also need to configure the `StreamFactory` to ignore unidentifiable records:

```
final StreamBuilder builder = new StreamBuilder("streamName")
    .readOnly()
    .format("fixedlength")
    .parser(new FixedLengthParserBuilder())
    .ignoreUnidentifiedRecords()             // <-- important
    .addGroup(...)
    .addRecord(RD.class));
factory.define(builder);
```